# Create a new ".xcodeproj" for iOS using command lines

Tags: ios, command-line, project, new-operator

I'd like to know how to create a new project for **iOS** using only command lines so I can use these lines in some script of mine.

I tried to look in Apple's sources and on the Internet but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a blank template project and just copy and rename it as needed.